# CloudKit records saving progress

Tags: ios, xcode, cloudkit

I want to save Event and Image (for event) records. I want to show uploading progress in UI.
Event is little object with text and location.
Image is big object with photo as UIImage.

Image record is first item in array, event is second.

I create `CKModifyRecordsOperation` and set two `CKRecord` objects to `recordsToSave`

Than I set `perRecordProgressBlock`:

```
[operation setPerRecordProgressBlock:^(CKRecord *record, double progress) {
    NSLog(@"#record: %@ progress: %f", record.recordType, progress);
}];
```

And `perRecordCompletionBlock`:

```
[operation setPerRecordCompletionBlock:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"#recordSaved: %@ e: %@", record.recordType, error);
}];
```

I expect to see a lot of rows with progress for two records like:

```
#record: ImageRecord progress: 0.050000
#record: ImageRecord progress: 0.100000
#record: ImageRecord progress: 0.150000
             ...
#record: ImageRecord progress: 1.000000
#recordSaved: ImageRecord e: (null)
#record: EventRecord progress: 0.050000
             ...
#record: EventRecord progress: 1.000000
#recordSaved: EventRecord e: (null)
```

But really in console output I see:

```
#record: ImageRecord progress: 0.000000
#record: ImageRecord progress: 0.447357
#record: ImageRecord progress: 1.000000
#record: ImageRecord progress: 1.000000
#recordSaved: Event e: (null)
#recordSaved: ImageRecord e: (null)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Hey AlKozin! Did you manage to find a solution for a smooth(er) progress using CloudKit?

Comment: @drdrdrdr Unfortunately, no. My solution is to approximately show progress according to value from operation but not change progress to exact values from operation.

Comment: save question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74407045/cloudkit-ckmodifyrecordsoperation-progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the `CKModifyRecordOperation` states:
The operation object executes this block zero or more times for each record in the recordsToSave property.

So if the save action for an object takes little time, then it could happen that you won't get a progress callback. As far as I know there is no way to influence the frequency of progress notifications.

Comment: Ok, this is no problem on wifi. On edge saving takes a lot of time, but I see only three progress callbacks in any case: on slow connection and on fast connection.

Comment: Maybe this is a bug? There is no benefit from the fact that I get callbacks at the beginning of the operation, in the middle and at the end.