# Progress on CloudKit/CKAsset upload

Tags: ios, user-interface, cloudkit

While saving a CKRecord with a CKAsset attached to it (with >500Kb in file size) I'd like to present a progress information to the user. Is there a reliable way to do this?

While [CKModifyRecordsOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKModifyRecordsOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CKModifyRecordsOperation) has a `perRecordProgressBlock` property it'll be called "...zero or more times..." according to the documentation. In my tests after adding this operation, a few seconds later the progress immediately jumps to 0.99 and then finishes with a 1.0 progress value - which is not useful to the user.

I have experimented with [NSProgress](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSProgress_Class/index.html) as well but got more or less the same disappointing results.

The code is straight forward and the upload in general runs fine but I'd like to provide more feedback to the user in case the upload takes more than just a few seconds.

```
CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:self.name];
self.record = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:@"burst" recordID:recordID];
self.record[@"image"] = [[CKAsset alloc] initWithFileURL:self.url];

CKModifyRecordsOperation *operation = [[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordsToSave:@[self.record] recordIDsToDelete:nil];
operation.database = [CKContainer defaultContainer].publicCloudDatabase;
operation.usesBackgroundSession = NO;
operation.perRecordProgressBlock = ^(CKRecord *record, double progress) {
    NSLog(@"progress %f", progress);
};
operation.perRecordCompletionBlock = ^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"OK");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
};

[[CKContainer defaultContainer].publicCloudDatabase addOperation:operation];
```

Comment: Try it with a large file. 500k is pretty small.

Comment: Hm, in fact I get strange results:  

- for 1.2MB I still only get two progress values

- for 2.2MB the progress block gets called way more often (50 times)

Comment: Why is that strange? Do the 50 calls return reasonable progress values?

Comment: @rmaddy thanks so far, the values itself are reasonable but the "jumps" between input file size and reported progress steps are strange...

Comment: Just saw that this [already has been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266589/cloudkit-records-saving-progress?rq=1)